# Flutter: How to handle exception for image/file empty path?

Tags: flutter, dart, nosuchmethoderror

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09eJJ.png)My API call works when all the fields are not empty.

But, I just want to update textfields without updating image. And when I trigger update button.

It shows:**Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'path' was called on null.

Receiver: null

Tried calling: path**

## This is my POST in API_CODE_FOLDER

```
void updateData(
BuildContext context,
int id,
int userID,
String name,
String nric,
String dob,
File img,
String mobileNo,
int gender,
String nationality,
int race,
int religion,
String occupation,
String maritalStatus,
String deleteAt,
String createAt,
String updateAt,)async {
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final mimeTypeData =
    lookupMimeType(img.path, headerBytes: [0xFF, 0xD8]).split('/');
final file = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('nric_front_copy', img.path,
    contentType: MediaType(mimeTypeData[0], mimeTypeData[1]));
refreshTokenApi(context);
print('UPDATE MOU');
accessToken = prefs.getString('access_token');
String myUrl = "$_url/personal_info";
var url = Uri.parse(myUrl);
var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", url);
request.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $accessToken';
request.fields['id'] = id.toString();
request.fields['user_id'] = id.toString();
request.fields['name'] = name.trim();
request.fields['nric'] = nric.trim();
request.fields['date_of_birth'] = dob.trim();
request.files..add(file);
request.fields['mobile_no'] = mobileNo.trim();
request.fields['gender'] = gender.toString();
request.fields['nationality'] = nationality.trim();
request.fields['race_id'] = race.toString();
request.fields['religion_id'] = religion.toString();
request.fields['occupation'] = occupation.toString();
request.fields['marital_status'] = maritalStatus.toString();
request.fields['deleted_at'] = '';
request.fields['created_at'] = '';
request.fields['updated_at'] = '';
request.fields['_method'] = 'PATCH';
request.send().then((response){
  print(response.statusCode);
  print(response);
     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/Dashboard');
    print("updated!");
  } else if (response.statusCode != 201) {
    print(response.statusCode);
  }
});
```

}

## This is my update

```
void updateButton() async {
print('TAPPED Update Button');
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
// IF id & user_id is not empty then UPDATE.
if (prefs.getInt('id') != null || prefs.getInt('user_id') != null) {
    setState((){
    _gender = genderCon.text.isEmpty ? 1 : int.parse(genderCon.text);
    race = raceCon.text.isEmpty ? 2 : int.parse(raceCon.text);
    religion = religionCon.text.isEmpty ? 3 : int.parse(religionCon.text);
    _nric = icCon.text;
    _dob = dobCon.text;
    _name = nameCon.text;
    print(nameCon.text);
    print(nameCon.text.trim());
    callApi.updateData(
        context,
        id,
        userID,
        _name,
        _nric,
        _dob,
        _image,
        phoneCon.text,
        _gender,
        nationality,
        race,
        religion,
        occupation,
        maritalStatus,
        deleteAt,
        createAt,
        updateAt);
    print('UPDATE');
  });
}
```

}

## This is my get image function

```
 void getImage() async {
var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
    source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 100);
setState(() {
  _image = image;
  Navigator.of(context);
});
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    void updateData(
    BuildContext context,
    int id,
    int userID,
    String name,
    String nric,
    String dob,
    File img,
    String mobileNo,
    int gender,
    String nationality,
    int race,
    int religion,
    String occupation,
    String maritalStatus,
    String deleteAt,
    String createAt,
    String updateAt,)async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    refreshTokenApi(context);
    print('UPDATE MOU');
    accessToken = prefs.getString('access_token');
    String myUrl = "$_url/personal_info";
    var url = Uri.parse(myUrl);
    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", url);

    if(img != null){
       final mimeTypeData =
            lookupMimeType(img.path, headerBytes: [0xFF, 0xD8]).split('/');
    final file = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('nric_front_copy', img.path,

           contentType: MediaType(mimeTypeData[0], mimeTypeData[1]));
           request.files..add(file);

        }

    request.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
    request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $accessToken';
    request.fields['id'] = id.toString();
    request.fields['user_id'] = id.toString();
    request.fields['name'] = name.trim();
    request.fields['nric'] = nric.trim();
    request.fields['date_of_birth'] = dob.trim();
    request.fields['mobile_no'] = mobileNo.trim();
    request.fields['gender'] = gender.toString();
    request.fields['nationality'] = nationality.trim();
    request.fields['race_id'] = race.toString();
    request.fields['religion_id'] = religion.toString();
    request.fields['occupation'] = occupation.toString();
    request.fields['marital_status'] = maritalStatus.toString();
    request.fields['deleted_at'] = '';
    request.fields['created_at'] = '';
    request.fields['updated_at'] = '';
    request.fields['_method'] = 'PATCH';
    request.send().then((response){
      print(response.statusCode);
      print(response);
         if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/Dashboard');
        print("updated!");
      } else if (response.statusCode != 201) {
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
    });
```

Comment: This problem mentioned above has been solved by Sonu Sharma, much appreciate to him.

Answer (score 1):

So essentially it says img is null and you are trying to access the method .path() on a null object.

So to stop this, you need to wrap your stuff with null checks. There are nicer ways to do this in dart such as `img?.path()` where it will only execute `path()` if img is not null.

However easiest way to get your code working is to wrap it in an if for the image part.

Try this:

```
void updateData(
BuildContext context,
int id,
int userID,
String name,
String nric,
String dob,
File img,
String mobileNo,
int gender,
String nationality,
int race,
int religion,
String occupation,
String maritalStatus,
String deleteAt,
String createAt,
String updateAt,)async {
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
refreshTokenApi(context);
print('UPDATE MOU');
accessToken = prefs.getString('access_token');
String myUrl = "$_url/personal_info";
var url = Uri.parse(myUrl);
var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", url);
request.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $accessToken';
request.fields['id'] = id.toString();
request.fields['user_id'] = id.toString();
request.fields['name'] = name.trim();
request.fields['nric'] = nric.trim();
request.fields['date_of_birth'] = dob.trim();
if(img != null)
{
    var mimeTypeData =
    lookupMimeType(img.path, headerBytes: [0xFF, 0xD8]).split('/');
    var file = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('nric_front_copy', img.path,
    contentType: MediaType(mimeTypeData[0], mimeTypeData[1]));
    request.files..add(file);
}
request.fields['mobile_no'] = mobileNo.trim();
request.fields['gender'] = gender.toString();
request.fields['nationality'] = nationality.trim();
request.fields['race_id'] = race.toString();
request.fields['religion_id'] = religion.toString();
request.fields['occupation'] = occupation.toString();
request.fields['marital_status'] = maritalStatus.toString();
request.fields['deleted_at'] = '';
request.fields['created_at'] = '';
request.fields['updated_at'] = '';
request.fields['_method'] = 'PATCH';
request.send().then((response){
  print(response.statusCode);
  print(response);
     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/Dashboard');
    print("updated!");
  } else if (response.statusCode != 201) {
    print(response.statusCode);
  }
});
```

Comment: This problem mentioned above has been solved by Jan as well. Thank your for the help.